# Groovorio. com gets me down, I can't remove it

Tags: google-chrome

I used to be careful when browsing online and never get suspicious apps or click any nasty websites. I have no idea how this groovorio gets inside and replaces my homepage. Now the chrome works like hell, with annoying floating ads.

Comment: What's your question? And what did you do so far to answer it yourself?

Comment: My question how can I remove it totally? I googled online and was told to remove its extension, browser cookies, and to reset homepage. But it goes back now.

Comment: [Groovorio Search and groovorio.com Removal Guide](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-groovorio-virus/) has complete removal instructions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

Answer (score 0):

How about [manual removal](http://blog.doohelp.com/how-to-get-rid-ofremove-groovorio-com-virus-quickly/)? You can search for and remove all files of goovorio from the browser, registry, program folder and more.